# NavigationView cannot pull down after the LongPressGesture NavigationLink is full of screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When I use `LongPressGesture` in `NavigationLink`, the `NavigationView` cannot pull down after the link is full of screen because the `LongPressGesture` and `NavigationView`'s pulling down have conflicts.

The code is as following:

```
VStack{
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
       NavigationLink(destination: Group
            { if self.isLongPressed { Destination2() } else { Destination1() } }, tag: index, selection: self.$currentTag
        ) {
            Text(self.lyrics[index])
        }


    }
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())  
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in })
```

Using two fingers to drag down `NavigationView` is also fine for me. But I do not know how to make it.

How to solve this bug and make pulling down `NavigationView` work? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add same TapGasture

```
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())  
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {})
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in })
```

Comment: I am sorry for that I did not tell the question clearly. The `TapGesture` has been used for go to destination 1 view and `LongPressGesture ` has been used for go to destination 2 view. So I think it will not work for me.